# Firestore: How bad would it be to handle a big chunk of ordered data in an array field?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have hundreds of sub collections of items and those items can be manually sorted by their owner.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to handle big chunk of sorted data in Firebase.

Right now I'm using an "order" field with a big integer value. When a new item is created I take the order of the previous item, add 1 000 000 to it, then set it to the new item.
But if an item is moved between 2 items, I need to update the order of it. So I take the difference between those 2 items, divide it by 2, then set the new order.

It goes like this

[image]

The limitation is that if I keep adding items between 2 other items then the diff will approach 1 (500 / 2 = 250, 250 / 2 = 125... 62... 31... 15... 7... 3...). At this point I won't be able to sort anything between those 2 items anymore.

So my first idea was to batch update all the following items once I get close to 1. It works but I don't like that solution.

So I'm wondering, what if I create an array field (in a lonely child doc) listing all the items ids then use it to list the items. Arrays are perfect for that so it's tempting.

Though, I know a Firestore doc can't get bigger than 1Mb so I'm wondering how plausible it is that I get to a doc of this size.

Also I'm wondering how bad this idea is. It's rare but some collection can have ~5000 items (could be more at some point).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an array the most common approach for keeping an order. The main problems with it are indeed the maximum document size, and the fact that you need to read the entire array to add/change an item in it.

The approach with subdividing the difference between the two items that you drop an item to is quite common too. I just use a floating point number, which reads a bit more natural in my view, and removes the minimum distance of 1 that you have. But there is still a limit to how many swaps you can do, as you approach the maximum precision of a floating point number on the platform where you perform the calculation, or in Firestore's backend.

There is no singular best between these options, it all depends on your use-case, how you access the database, and how many times you reasonable expect to perform the operations. I typically use arrays when the numbers are low, and even for medium sizes if I can perform the operation on a server (where bandwidth is not an issue). For larger systems I use a floating point `ranking` field, and tend to ignore the maximum precision of that. If forced I'd probably try to come up with an elegant way to periodically reset the `ranking` values.

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank. Didn't think the floating point number was an option. If I pair it with the periodical reset I think I have a decent solution for my current issue. Thanks

Comment: Ditto here, I also initially came up with this approach with whole numbers that were far enough apart. Then a team mate pointed at the float option, and another team mate pointed out that it essentially has the same precision problem once you swap frequently enough. :)

Comment: I wonder how many items could be inserted between 2 given ranking. Since 2^20 = 1 000 000, I guess it means I can insert 20 items if my limit is 1 (no floating point numbers) and if I add a delta of 1 000 000 between each item. Not sure if that math is correct though. And I wonder how much items I could insert with the same delta but with floating point numbers